# ruby system call is quitting process

Tags: ruby

Im trying to do this:

```
current_size = exec("ps -o rss $(pgrep rake)")
```

When it runs, I get:

RSS
 2784
  560
  568
  788

but the process exits.

Any idea what im doing wrong?

I also tried:

```
 exec("ps -o rss #{Process.pid}")
```

Same problem

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? `ps` outputs a list of processes and then exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From "ri Kernel.exec"

```
Replaces the current process by running the given external _command_
```

Your process has been replaced by the ps process which prints out the data and then exits.

You probably want Kernel.`

```
 Returns the standard output of running _cmd_ in a subshell. The
 built-in syntax +%x{...}+ uses this method. Sets +$?+ to the
 process status.
```

Using %x{ } seems like the better option.

```
current_size = %x{ ps -o rss $(pgrep rake) }
```